# Conntrack shows no result

Tags: iptables, conntrack, nf-conntrack

I tried the command `conntrack -L` and it returns nothing when I have a `ping www.google.com` running.

I also tried to load the module by `modprobe nf_conntrack`. But it still always returns `conntrack v1.0.0 (conntrack-tools): 0 flow entries have been shown.`

Any one know what would be the solution?

Comment: I have the same result on Ubuntu 18.04. Although I load nf_conntrack_ipv4, nf_conntrack, nf_conntrack_netlink module, `conntrack -L` returns `0 flow entries have been shown`. Do you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding iptables rules with conntrack states for ex:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

It worked for me.

Comment: As written, this rule would allow all traffic. It is probably not desirable to include NEW in here.

Comment: worked for me too. But why?

Comment: @tinyhare that's because `conntrack` module is not loaded by default. To have a `conntrack` table, you should have `conntrack` module loaded and also have relevant `iptables` rules.

It's a lazy behavior I think. Conntrack won't be active unless required.

Comment: for nftables user，add ct state rule to a ‘type filter hook input’ base chain： nft add rule inet filter_example input_example ct state established,related accept

Answer (score 2):

The `conntrack` tool won't return a flow because, by the time your `ping` command has ended the flow has been terminated.

Create a persistent TCP connection to something on the Internet and do a `conntrack -L` and you'll see a flow. You could also send some `ping` requests to an Internet host that doesn't respond-- you'll see a flow created (waiting for the ICMP echo replies that will never come) that way, too.

Comment: Hi Evan, I tried to use nmap to generate some TCP connects as well and I am sure there are flows since I have wireshark on at the same time. Just don't know why couldn't see anything in conntrack

Comment: `nmap` isn't really a good tool to use on the `iptables` machine itself to generate test flows because, depending on the arguments, it may be using raw sockets to increase performance (or to do "evil" things that the kernel IP stack won't do).

Comment: @manxing rather than using nmap, use good ol' telnet instead. E.g.: `telnet www.google.com 80`

Answer (score 1):

adding iptables rules worked，and nftables is instead of the legacy {ip,ip6,arp,eb}_tables (xtables) infrastructure.

for nftables you can do it like this：

add **ct state** rule to a **type filter hook input** chain

```
nft add table inet filter_example
nft add chain inet filter_example input_example {type filter hook input priority filter\; policy accept\;}
nft add rule inet filter_example input_example ct state established,related accept
```

[image]